# Using kfree on kernel modules

Tags: memory-management, kernel, kernel-module

Good afternoon SO-

First time using kmallocs and kfrees, and I'm running into errors.

```
struct module* mod;
const struct kernel_symbol* ksymbol;

ksymbol = kmalloc(sizeof(struct kernel_symbol), GFP_KERNEL);
if(!sym | !dst | (dst_sz <= 0)) return -EFAULT;

mutex_lock(&module_mutex);

mod = (struct module*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct module), GFP_KERNEL);
ksymbol = find_symbol(sym, &mod, NULL, true, false);

if(!mod){
  for(i = 0; i < dst_sz; i++) dst[i] = '\0';
  mutex_unlock(&module_mutex);
  kfree(ksymbol);
  kfree(mod);
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

I've got other cases (!mod is for when the module is built into kernel), but why is this producing errors? At first I had...

```
  kfree(ksymbol);
  kfree(mod);
  mutex_unlock(&module_mutex);
  return SUCCESS;
```

And that resulted in segfaults. I thought maybe it was because I can't free before I unlock, so I went ahead and put mutex unlock at the top (like shown in the bigger code section), and that just says "Killed". What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Could you explain what would you like to accomplish? I suppose it is not really necessary to create `struct module` instances manually. Even if it is, calling `find_symbol()` on the newly allocated and not initialized yet `struct module` may result in a kernel oops at best. Perhaps, its was what you have seen ("Killed" for a user-space process, there should also be an oops report in the system log).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for late reply.

From viewing you code i can say that .

```
ksymbol = find_symbol(sym, &mod, NULL, true, false);
```

You are assigning to a constant. which can result in error.

But otherwise can you post the error.